# Simple form submission gives missing resource on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Apologies if this seems mundane, but I am a huge beginner to MVC and this seemingly simple task is giving me a massive headache.

I can't understand why my code isn't working. I'm submitting a form from my Index.cshtml and the postback is telling me the resource /Index (the page I am posting from) doesn't exist.

Could I please get some help on what I am doing wrong?

**My View (Index.cshtml):**

```
@model MyProject.Connection

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div id="container" class="container centered primary">
    @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <img src="@Url.Content("/Content/images/default.png")" alt="CMGR Web" />
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <fieldset id="fs_server" class="borderless!T">
            <legend>Server details</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.serverHost)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.serverHost)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.instanceName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.instanceName)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="fs_user" class="borderless!T">
            <legend>Your credentials</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.username)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.username)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.password)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(c => c.password)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.remember)
                    @Html.Label("Remember me?")
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    }
</div>
```

**My Model (Connection.cs):**

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class Connection
    {
        [Display(Name="Server Host")]
        public string serverHost { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Instance Name")]
        public string instanceName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string username { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string password { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Remoting Password")]
        public string remotingPassword { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Persistent")]
        public bool remember { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My Controller (IndexController.cs)**

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class IndexController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Login/

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        private ActionResult Index(Connection channel)
        {
            return View();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch that should not be an issue I think

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - you don't need to do that when you're posting to the same controller and action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Post ActionResult is set to Private so it isnt accessible. Change it to public

```
    private ActionResult Index(Connection channel)
    {
        return View();
    }  

    public ActionResult Index(Connection channel)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Good catch. I missed that.